# Delete rows by testing multiple columns againts a range of test values

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

If I have a matrix or table of data,

```
Data = {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 5}, {5, 6, 7}, {7, 8, 9}, {9, 10, 11}, {11, 12, 
  13}, {13, 14, 15}, {15, 16, 17}, {17, 18, 19}, {19, 20, 21}, {21, 
  22, 23}, {23, 24, 25}, {25, 26, 27}, {27, 28, 29}, {29, 30, 
  31}, {31, 32, 33}}
```

Is there a method of deleting or dropping a row if any column has the value defined by a list, e.g.

`TestList = {1, 8 , 16, 24}`

such that if any element contains one of those values then the row itself is removed?

It's achievable by using nested `Select` statements where you would have a `Select` for each column and test them individually against the list, using `MemberQ` but that seems a little crude.

Comment: Something like `Select[Data, Intersection[TestList, #] === {} &]`?

Comment: Can this also work for the opposite case? So Select all columns which do not contain any of the test list values?

Comment: You might be interested in using `Transpose[]` for that.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a play, your first suggestion works great!

Comment: Also take a look at [`ContainsNone`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContainsNone.html) and similar functions: They are really only syntactic sugar, but they make for very readable code. For instance, your row-wise requirement could be written as `Select[Data, ContainsNone[TestList]]`.

Comment: Toying around with some basic functions:
`Complement[data, 
 Flatten[Cases[data, x_List /; MemberQ[x, #]] & /@ testList, 1]]`

Comment: @MarcoB That is really super useful, how would you apply it to targeted columns if my data has more than three say, but i want to apply the filter only on columns 1,2, and 3? Usually I would use a logical operator like AND or OR for the columns I wanted but that wouldn't work here I think

Comment: @Q.P. See if I got what you mean in my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's create some play data:

```
SeedRandom[1234]
data = RandomInteger[{1, 20}, {10, 5}]

testlist = {2, 15, 19};

(*
{{ 2,  2,  1, 17, 18}, 
 { 5,  6, 20, 16, 17},
 {20,  3, 13,  6, 17},
 {19,  8, 15, 17,  7},
 { 2, 16,  8,  9, 14},
 {14,  2, 16,  9,  5},
 { 3, 17,  5, 17,  2},
 {14, 18, 10, 12,  7},
 {15, 19, 12,  3,  5},
 {17, 16, 12, 10, 15}}
*)
```

Your first task, as stated in the question, can be accomplished with:

```
Select[data, ContainsNone[testlist]]

(* {{ 5,  6, 20, 16, 17},
    {20,  3, 13,  6, 17},
    {14, 18, 10, 12,  7}} *)
```

The second task you outlined in comments, wanting to apply the filter only on certain columns (say, for instance, the first, third, and fourth), could be done with:

```
Select[data, ContainsNone[#[[{1, 3, 4}]], testlist] &]

(* 
{{ 5,  6, 20, 16, 17}, 
 {20,  3, 13,  6, 17},
 {14,  2, 16,  9,  5},
 { 3, 17,  5, 17,  2}, 
 {14, 18, 10, 12,  7},
 {17, 16, 12, 10, 15}} *)
```

Comment: Really awesome answer, short and simple!